# Bootstrap Slider Bar - Click event error

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap slider in my html for age range.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <input id="age_range" type="text" ui-jq="slider" class="slider form-control" value="" data-slider-min="13" data-slider-max="80" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[13,80]">
</div>
```

`slideStop` event is working fine on the slider, But when I am clicking on the slider the value is not getting properly

Here is my Jquery code

```
$('#age_range').on('slideStop change', function (ev) {
 range_val = $(this).val();
 console.log(range_val);
 $("#campaign_age_range_min").val(range_val.split(',')[0]);
 $("#campaign_age_range_max").val(range_val.split(',')[1]);
});
```

My version of slider is `bootstrap-slider.js v2.0.0`

Answer (score 3):

Well, is old post but here is your solution:

```
$('#age_range').on('slide slideStop', function (ev) {
    var range_val = ev.value;
    console.log(range_val);
    $("#campaign_age_range_min").val(range_val.split(',')[0]);
    $("#campaign_age_range_max").val(range_val.split(',')[1]);
});
```

You must use `event.value`, in your case `ev.value`.

That's all.

When something not work in javascript, put in `console.log()` all events and look what's happen and what objects you have there.

Comment: We didnt have slideStop, worked perfectly with it! Thanks!